# Rails 5: Can write checkbox fields to db with collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I'm trying to allow multiple checkbox fields to be selected in a simple form:

```
<%= form_with(model: coffee_roast, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if coffee_roast.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(coffee_roast.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this coffee_roast from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% coffee_roast.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <strong><%= form.label :name %></strong>
    <%= form.text_field :name, id: :coffee_roast_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <strong><%= form.label :bean,"Select bean(s)" %></strong>
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:coffee_roast, :coffee_beans, CoffeeBean.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The collection_check_box is working perfectly pulling values from another model via a join table.  My models are:

**coffee_bean.rb**

```
class CoffeeBean < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_roasts, through: :coffee_blends
end
```

**coffee_roast.rb**

```
class CoffeeRoast < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :roaster
    has_many :coffee_blends
    has_many :coffee_beans, through: :coffee_blends
    has_many :flavours, through: :coffee_flavours
end
```

And the join table

**coffee_blend.rb**

```
class CoffeeBlend < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :coffee_bean
    belongs_to :coffee_roast
end
```

*the problem*

When I save a `coffee_roast` and select a couple of checkboxes, the record is created without error, but I don't see any IDs populated in the join table.

I suspect it might be down to not permitting the ids in the `coffee_roast_controller.rb`

I've tried a few variations, but can't get it to work. This is my latest try:

```
def coffee_roast_params
  params.require(:coffee_roast).permit(:name, :coffee_bean_name, coffee_bean_id:[])
end
```

Comment: Could you post what `params` you get in your controller when you save the `coffee_roast` ? Also, try putting a breakpoint in your controller action and call `coffee_roast_params`, you will probably get a warning like 'Unpermitted params: some_param' to help you find out what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to like below

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :coffee_bean_ids, CoffeeBean.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name do |cb| %>
    <% cb.label(class: "checkbox-inline input_checkbox") {cb.check_box(class: "checkbox") + cb.text } %>
<% end %>
```

and in the controller params

```
coffee_bean_ids:[]
```

instead of `coffee_bean_id:[]`

Comment: This has worked. What's happening here, versus my original effort?